# Apache Camel: complete exchanges when an aggregated exchange is completed

Tags: apache-camel

In my Apache Camel application, I have a very simple route:

```
from("aws-sqs://...")
    .aggregate(constant(true), new AggregationStrategy())
    .completionSize(100)
    .to("SEND_AGGREGATE_VIA_HTTP");
```

That is, it takes messages from AWS SQS, groups them in batches of 100, and sends them via HTTP somewhere.

Exchanges with messages from SQS are completed successfully on getting into the aggregate stage, and `SqsConsumer` deletes them from the queue at this point.

The problem is that something might happen with an aggregated exchange (it might be delivered with an error), and messages will be lost. I would really like these original exchanges to be completed successfully (messages to be deleted from a queue) only when an aggregated exchange they're in is also completed successfully (a batch of messages is delivered). Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You want to delete the message from the queue only when the exchange has completely successfully?

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti yes, but only when aggregated exchange is completed.

Comment: I am not familar with sqs but does it have the ability define a backout queue? For instance, if an error occurs during processing the message is pushed to that queue rather than just be gone. Otherwise perhaps there is a way to set the entire process as one giant transaction and only when the transaction is done is the message removed from the queue.

Answer (score 1):

You could set `deleteAfterRead` to `false` and manually delete the messages after you've sent them to you HTTP endpoint; You could use a bean or a processor and send the proper SQS delete requests through the AWS SDK library. It's a workaround, granted, but I don't see a better way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you Miloš. This sounds like the best workaround I've found. If I find no direct way, I'll go for this.

Comment: There's also one other thing you could try - specify the batch size in the SQS URI and use the aggregator's `completionFromBatchConsumer` option instead of the `completionSize` you're using now. I'm not sure if it will help but it should be fairly easy to try.